# Using HDMI cable and Miracast simultaneously to duplicate laptop screen on two LED TVs

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, miracast

I want to duplicate my laptop screen on two TVs - one is using Miracast and another is HDMI cable. But when I connect to both - one TV is showing my extended desktop screen (the Miracast) while the other is showing my duplicated screen (the HDMI cable). How to prevent the extended screen and show a duplication of my screen instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose in which mode you can use the TV that you connect with hdmi from the display options. (extended screen , duplicated screen ...)

But I don't know the miracast program. There should probably be an option to change it in settings.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can't choose the mode with Miracast.